# Strange occurrences when calling python script from batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, command-line, executable

I'm writing a python script to post-process data from a measurement tool at my work. When the measurement is finished, the measurement program has the option to queue an external program. So I have it call a batch file which then passes a couple of arguments to a python script which does the bulk of the work. The reason I don't call the python script directly from the measurement program is because you need to pass it the path to an executable.

When I run the python script by itself, it works fine. But when I use the command line to call the batch file which then calls the python script, it acts much differently.

For example, I have multiple try,except clauses to catch any errors. In the except clauses, I open a log file and write the error description. I started from the top of the program and worked my way down during debugging. When I commented out all but the first try,except clause, and set the parameters such that it would throw an error that would be caught by the first except clause (thus writing to the log file), the program worked the same when run directly from spyder or the command prompt. But then when I uncommented the first and second try,except clauses, it worked fine when run directly from spyder, but nothing happened when I queued it from the command line. There were no compilation errors, so I don't understand why it wouldn't at least fall into the first except clause and write that error to the text file (in each except clause I'm opening and closing the file, so the program never terminates with the file opened).

I also noticed that there were a couple of libraries that I imported that I didn't use - in spyder, it would simply give me a warning on that line number indicating that the library wasn't used, but it would still let me run the code without error. But if I left the import statement for the unused library active without commenting it out, queueing the batch file that calls the python script would lead to no output.

Has anyone ever run across something strange like this before?

Comment: The environment may be different in the two cases. At the start of the program write `sys.argv` and `os.environ` to a file using an absolute path name, then exit. Are there differences?

Comment: You might be able to effectively call the Python script by passing `sys.executable` as the exe program with the path to Python file as an argument (and possibly other arguments that the script will see as command-line arguments passed to _it_.

Comment: @tdelaney Unfortunately it's a bit tricky, when I run the program directly from python I can't pass any command line arguments, so the output from sys.argv when running from the batch file and when running directly from spyder are different, but the code still acted differently even when I didn't utilize the command line arguments that I passed to it.
When I print out the os.environ, I get differences in the PATH variable when I run it from the command line vs spyder, and there are also some variables that are only present in the former case.

Comment: @martineau Yes that actually does work, that's a good idea since it saves having that intermediate step. But somehow it's still not working properly. If I simplify the script and simply have it write the command line arguments to a text file, it works flawlessly, but somehow if I expand it to include other elements of the script I get no output at all. So the problem is somehow tied to being called from the command prompt.
I have multiple imported libraries like pyodbc and pandas - could this be causing an issue (environment related issue)?

Comment: David: It's hard to imagine why something would _need_ to be called from the command-line in order to work. If you could somehow figure out **why** there's no output, then maybe something could be done to fix it…

Comment: So I've narrowed it down, somehow the pandas library is the one that's causing an issue. Having the 'import pandas'  statement enabled causes it not to run when called from the command prompt - how can I ensure that I'm utilizing the same environment when calling it from spyder and when calling it from cmd?